# Can I open ports 23 and 22 on a F@st 5355 home router that doesn't allow it in the web GUI

Tags: router, home-networking

As I said in the title I want to open the ports for ssh and telnet mainly on my home router anyway possible. So far I've tried the tutorial at [Sorry Telstra but this is my F@ST 5355 router](https://medium.com/@thafresh/isps-doing-whatever-they-like-with-our-hardware-118d727fc76e) by ThaFresh and the router logs me out when I try the first step, I've also thought about reflashing the firmware chip manually to a previous version that the exploit worked on.

Does anyone have any Ideas or is this the wrong community to ask on

Comment: Why don't you just ditch this router and buy something that works for your usage case?  This router looks to be a joke with VDSL and Gigabit wan ports, but only ethernet LAN ports, and a raft of known bugs ADVERTISED IN THE MANUAL!     Looking at this POS, if I had to use it, I'd turn it into bridge mode and put a router that supports DD-WRT behind it.

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)